# Can Envoy Proxy be used to wrap a third-party API?

Tags: api, proxy, circuit-breaker, envoyproxy

I'm looking for to utilize a more mainstream and language-agnostic API proxy/wrapper for implementing common patterns (eg, circuit breaker, health checks, etc.) and tracking stats for API calls.

However, this wrapper would be for remote third-party APIs rather than my own internal SOA/microservice APIs.

It seems this would be similar to Hystrix or Phystrix but running as its own proxy and not language-dependent.

I've seen Envoy Proxy (created by Lyft) before but it looks like it's only for wrapping internal services.

Can that be used for wrapping third-party APIs or is there a better proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Envoy Proxy on its own as an egress proxy for a 3rd party external service.

I was able to set it up as a simple proxy (just adding authorisation headers) using [this example](https://github.com/saikris12/blog/tree/master/boot-envoy-egress), but modified with a route prefix of "\" and adjusting the destination "cluster".

Your app would have to be configured to point to the proxy, so it wouldn't be transparent. You'd have to configure and manage the stats yourself.